Batch Not Executing Fully From Access
I am running a batch file from MSAccess in VBA. It is not fully executing. It works just fine if I run it outside of access. I am using VBA to create the bat file and then running it and quitting access. The bat file will then delete the access file and then download a new file and open the new one. Like I said when I run the bat file outside of access it works perfectly. But from access it deletes the current file and then never continues on with the rest of the script. Any guidance would be welcomed.
Code In Access:
Private Sub UpdateFrontEnd(ByVal LocalFilePath As String)
 
Dim BatchFile As String
Dim Restart As String
Dim ShellCommand As String

    BatchFile = CurrentProject.Path & "\updater.bat"
    
    Restart = """" & LocalFilePath & """"
    
    ShellCommand = "Invoke-WebRequest http://downloadipaddress/filename.accdb -OutFile filename.accdb"
 
    Open BatchFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, "@Echo Off"
    Print #1, "ECHO Deleting old file..."
    Print #1, ""
    Print #1, "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul"
    Print #1, ""
    Print #1, "Del """ & LocalFilePath & """"
    Print #1, ""
    Print #1, "ECHO Downloading new file..."
    Print #1, "powershell -Command " & ShellCommand; ""
    Print #1, ""
    Print #1, "ECHO Starting Microsoft Access..."
    Print #1, "START /I " & """MSAccess.exe"" " & Restart
    Close #1
 
    Shell BatchFile
 
    DoCmd.Quit
End Sub

I have tired splitting it into 2 differeant bat files and calling the second from the first but still same result.
I also tried just running the bat and not creating it in the VBA code but still same result.
Batch File Code
@echo off

echo Deleting old file...
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul

del "C:\filepath\filename.accdb"

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul

echo Downloading new file...
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://downloadaddress/filename.accdb -OutFile filename.accdb"

ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul

echo Starting Microsoft Access...
start /i "MSAccess.exe" "C:\filepath\filename.accdb"

Also when running this from access using cmd.exe /k it does delete the file and "downloads the file" shows a progress bar and file size for it, but does not. But again when I double-click it works. Deletes the file, downloads the new one, starts it up in access.

It works just fine if I run it outside of Access. ... Then, why run it inside Access? But very last sentence contradicts your claim that it runs perfectly outside Access.

You don't need a batch file to run ping.exe, you don't need one to delete a file, and you don't need one  to open an application. So why not just run a powershell command or script instead.

So to be more clear, when I execute the bat file from access it stops at the delete and does not download the new file. If I execute the bat by double clicking, it deletes the old file and downloads the new one and launches it. The purpose of this is to auto update my front end file, so I would like it to be ran from access executing the file. the bat is created using VBA. Then VBA runs the bat. Even if just using VBA to run the bat and creating it in the directory, it is still stopping after the delete and not downloading the new file.

Probably because the batch run is waiting for user input from the del prompt. "are you sure you want to delete..." so how about adding parameters /F / Q

Probably a timing issue. But study my article and script: Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click.

Your batch file should read as start "" /i "MSAccess.exe" "C:\filepath\filename.accdb", and I'd ask you to be sure that you even need the /i option.

Consider following changes:

Evoke cmd.exe in the Shell command which mimics the double click of batch file outside Access;
Change directory with cd to where batch file sits;
Run the wait for command ping after the delete and PowerShell commands to allow those steps to complete;
Properly quote the PowerShell command;
Use Application.Quit a synonymous form to legacy DoCmd.Quit which is the recommended version per MS docs.

Private Sub UpdateFrontEnd(ByVal LocalFilePath As String)
 
    Dim BatchFile As String, Restart As String, ShellCommand As String

    BatchFile = CurrentProject.Path & "\updater.bat"
    
    ShellCommand = "Invoke-WebRequest https://downloadipaddress/filename.accdb -OutFile filename.accdb"
 
    Open BatchFile For Output As #1
      Print #1, "@echo off"
      Print #1, ""
      Print #1, "cd /D %~dp0"
      Print #1, ""
      Print #1, "echo Deleting old file..."
      Print #1, "del """ & LocalFilePath & """"
      Print #1, ""
      Print #1, "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul"
      Print #1, ""
      Print #1, "echo Downloading new file..."
      Print #1, "powershell -Command """ & ShellCommand & """"
      Print #1, ""
      Print #1, "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul"
      Print #1, ""
      Print #1, "echo Starting Microsoft Access..."
      Print #1, "start /i MSAccess.exe """ & LocalFilePath & """"
    Close #1
 
    Shell "cmd.exe /c " & BatchFile, vbNormalFocus
    Application.Quit

End Sub


This did not work. Using this code, the batch did not even delete when executed from access. And again batch works just perfectly if I just double-click. I even tried just using VBA to just execute the batch and write it. Same result. When I double-click the batch window stays open and runs. When executed from access, the window flashes really fast and then nothing happens.

The /c is meant to close after run. Use /k to keep cmd open. How long does double clicking batch take? Are you prompted for anything when double clicking? Is the PowerShell file, filename.accdb, saving over front end? If so, don't call del. PS may be raising error. Is LocalFilePath the same as current DB running this routine? Post the .bat file that works perfectly.

Issue may be directory location. See updated answer where I recommend adding cd and properly quoting the PowerShell command.

So I changed /c to /k and I was able to see that it was stopping at the del command trying to go to a file path with a folder that had a space in the name. I removed the space and it got past that point then when starting the download it runs the command, acts like it is downloading, but does not, it keeps going and says it cant find the file and stops, and again when I double click it works just fine. Yes it is all running from the same directory. I will add batch file to original post.

The multiple quoting in VBA should have allowed spaces. I also noticed the PowerShell website differs from VBA and batch file, namely protocol: http vs https. I also fixed the cd line in my answer. Please fix site and try again.
